# 2D Self-Deconvolution in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, signals, signal-processing, convolution

I have some data, a 2D matrix we'll call A, which I know in theory can be described by a self-convolution of another matrix we'll call B:

```
A=conv2(B,B)
```

I am trying to extract B. Is there a way to perform a self deconvolution of a 2D matrix in MATLAB? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried the `deconvblind` , `deconvlucy` , `deconvreg` or`deconvwnr`  functions? Just a shot in the dark. I believe that It is a quite under-determined system, the deconvolution of an image, so probably  not possible, or possible only using regularization techniques and prior information. If you dont get an answer here, I suggest you try in the math stackoverflow

Comment: By a 2D matrix, do you mean you have something like {{1,0,0},{2,2,0},{1,2,1}} that you want to recognize as the convolution square of {{1,0},{1,1}}?

Comment: You could theoretically find **one** of the solutions by performing the Fourier transform, taking the square root of the frequency image (using `sqrtm()`), then perfom the inverse Fourier transform. However, you would need to take in account the fact that FFT tranforms *circular* transform into multiplications, and I failed to find a function performing directly DTFT in MATLAB (which is pretty logical since FFT are samples of DTFT)- so padding should somehow be used. I tried a few times and definitely could not make it work because of this last problem, but I think this is the right direction.

Comment: @AnderBiguri thanks for the suggestions. I looked into those function, but they seem to be dealing with deconvolution to remove blurriness in an image, and I don't think they actually return the matrix that was convolved with the image

Comment: @Yellows It sounds like you are suggesting something similar to the convolution theorem, but not quite. The series of steps you described doesn't seem to be consistent with the convolution theorem, which makes me think it may not be correct. Where did you get this information?

Comment: @DouglasZare yes, pretty much, although I'm not sure what you mean by convolution square

Comment: @Beth Why do you think it is inconsistent with the convolution theorem? See [here](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~az/lectures/sa/lect12.pdf) p. 36.

Comment: @Yellows ahh sorry, you are right. It's been a while since I looked at it. Thanks for the suggestion, it does seem like the right direction.

Comment: @Beth Happy I might have helped. Please let us know how you achieved it.

Comment: Could you say something about the dimensions of the matrices?

Answer (score 0):

We can view A as the coefficients a polynomial in two variables, and we want to find a polynomial B so that B^2 = A. This type of calculation is not what Matlab was designed to do, but I think if you have the symbolic math toolbox, you can make a symbolic polynomial from A, take the square root, and convert this back to a matrix of coefficients. If the coefficients of A are noisy, then you might evaluate A and then sqrt(A) on several (x,y) points away from where A is 0, fit a polynomial B to those values, and extract the coefficients from B. -B will also work. Try not to choose points separated by a curve where A is 0, or you might mix values of B and -B.